# Can I filter two columns differently in an Excel pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot

I have a table that is like that:

[image: Excel table representing the dataset]

I need to create a chart that compares ITEM A,B and C, by their values over the years.
As a result:

[image: Chart containing 2 items compared]

Ideally it should be able to compare them by selecting the filters of the ITEMS (Filter A and B and compare them, filter A, B and C and compare them...)

Comment: Your example and question is not clear, please edit. Show a screenshot from Pivot and expect result.

Comment: Can you check if it is possible to help now please?

Comment: What is your problem? How did you create your graph? It is certainly possible -- just select the items you wish to compare in your filter field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I do not unterstand the question correct, because your chart seams to base on the data you shown and you set the filter. 
You can solve this with a pivot chart. For a clearer answer I put in the following picture the Pivottable also.

(1) The Chart without filtering
(2) Filter the Item (which are in Columns of the Pivot respectively in the Legend of the chart)

[image]